# GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent keeps reinstalling itself and connecting to Google Update Servers

Tags: google-chrome, google-drive, osx-el-capitan, little-snitch

I'm using LittleSnitch on OS X 10.11.6 to see outgoing connections and have previously noticed how ksfetch keeps trying to connect for Updates, launched with changing names by GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent so that it prompts a different request every time.

I have uninstalled all Google Software (Chrome, Drive) and used the --nuke option on the GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent Bundle, yet something keeps reinstalling the Google folder and trying to connect. See screenshot below.

How can I make sure that there is no more Google Software installed on my system?

[image: Google Software Update via ksfetch]

Comment: Why don't you just throw the entire Google folder in the trash, or tell Little Snitch to block ksfetch entirely?

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly my problem: After deleting and restarting the folder keeps coming back, Little Snitch cannot block because ksfetch starts new random processes in /private/tmp/ (see above).

Comment: Workaround might be to replace the folder with an empty, locked one; but idk how/where the new one is coming from. I actually have ksfetch allowed in Little Snitch for the entire google domain, & it only ever asked the first time.